# Haproxy "timeout server" on a specific action

Tags: timeout, haproxy

I'm wondering is it possible to set an alternative "timeout server" on a specific action (url path)? For example, something like

`timeout server 1000
timeout server /something-that-takes-long-time-to-respond 10000`

?

Answer (score 2):

This may be solved using separate backends.

```
frontend www-http
    bind 10.0.0.1:80
    default_backend app

    acl long_url  path_beg -i /long_url

    use_backend app-extended if long_url

backend app
    server web-1 10.0.0.2:80 check

backend app-extended
    server web-1 10.0.0.2:80 trace app/web-1
    timeout server 10m
```

Such configuration allows executing time consuming links and configure longer timeout only for specific url.

Please note that trace setting, which makes only one health check instead of separate ones to the same server.